# Is this a valid datetime value: 00-2-11-30T00:00:00.000+02:00

Tags: c#, timestamp

I just received some data from a reputable source with the following date value.  Is this valid and if so what format is it?

```
   <date> 00-2-11-30T00:00:00.000+01:00</date>
```

Comment: This is Invalid Date

Comment: No, it is not a valid datetime according to any normal standard. It _could_ conform to some exotic format, but that's impossible to guess. Ask the reputable source about the format they mangled this into.

Comment: The problem with asking about "unknown" date formats where all you give is one (or a few) examples and *don't know what date that's meant to correspond to* is - how would you even validate an answer someone gave you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is this why its being downvoted so much? I have never seen a type like this. I thought someone more knowledgeable would recognize if it was valid and I would look through the net for whatever format they thought it was and validate as such from others examples. If it was valid, there would be more than one mention of it somewhere online.

Answer (score 0):

It's look similar to *Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second* from https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime but i dont think it's valid data (i don't know what "00-2" that part is)